# Windows file permissions as string

Tags: c++, windows, api

Given a specific file system path (folder or file, doesn't matter), I need to generate a string that reflects each principal's access to that path.

The result I'm after would be very similar to what you see in the Permissions tab of the Advanced Security Settings dialog in Windows:

[image: Windows Advanced Security Dialog]

which I will ultimately display in a `User1: [access], User2: [access], etc.` format.

What is the straight-forward method of achieving this result? Specifically, which Windows security API functions must be executed, and in what order?

Answer (score 2):

Open the file via [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS and FILE_GENERIC_READ attributes (or'd together).

Then with the obtained file handle, call [GetKernelObjectSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Then parse out the SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR that is returned by this call.

You'll likely need to learn about ACLs and DACLs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have an example of parsing out the SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR in a manner consistent with my original question?

Comment: @Mark: You can get a quick start with [`ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Roman: That function does indeed convert a security descriptor to a string, but the result is not primarily designed for human readability. I've looked for ways to convert to those to friendlier formats (like the one I described in my original question, but to no avail).

Comment: @Mark: Yes but you have choice now whether you want to parse more or less readable string (though not sufficiently human friendly), or a binary thing.